# Ruby on rails on Jailed shell cpanel on centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, shell, centos

I am trying to install ruby on rails on a shared server with Cpanel with Jailed Shell on SSH. 
I've this

```
-jailshell: rbenv: command not found
```

when server is starting.
After downloading the Ruby tar package, I navigated inside the folder and ran the commands,

```
make
```

and

```
make install
```

and

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ruby -exec-prefix=/usr/local/ruby
```

once and it didn't work
tried even this

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ -exec-prefix=/usr/local/
```

the command `make install` results in the following

```
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/ruby (Errno::EACCES)
from /home/username/ruby-2.1.1/lib/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
from /home/username/ruby-2.1.1/lib/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /home/username/ruby-2.1.1/lib/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
from /home/username/ruby-2.1.1/lib/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /home/username/ruby-2.1.1/lib/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
from /home/username/ruby-2.1.1/lib/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:193:in `makedirs'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:300:in `prepare'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:339:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:789:in `call'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:789:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:786:in `each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:786:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

My service provider says it's the max level of access he can give me.

Tried installing it from CPANEL Ruby on rails installation. No luck from there either.

Any workarounds to install ruby, rvm and rails?

Thanks.

P.S. Tried a lot of methods posted online, no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to continue using that service provider? Cloud servers are ~2-3$ per month nowadays, I sincerily wonder why would you want to use such an ancient solution.

Comment: That's where I ultimately tend to go, This is just a stand by.